# Spring use bean from applicationContext in security-context.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have following entries

web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

applicationContext:

```
<bean id="myUserDAO" class="no.java.UserDAOImpl">
    <property name="DataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

in spring-security.xml
i have following entry:

```
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="no.java.SimpleUserDetailsService" >
            <property name="UserDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
 </bean>
```

and now i'm gettting following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'property'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
```

as far as i understand i should be getting something like bean myUserDAO undefined or something similar, but i'm not. I'd be really greatful for any help as i'm enjoying this error for quite a few hours right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML is not well formed, this

```
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="no.java.SimpleUserDetailsService" >
    <property name="UserDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
</bean>
```

should be

```
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="no.java.SimpleUserDetailsService" >
    <beans:property name="UserDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
</beans:bean>
```